# Where do I ask questions about the TypeScript compiler?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm curious about the reasoning behind a design decision of the TypeScript compiler.  On which site does this question belong?  I don't need help with my own code, so I don't think it belongs on Stack Overflow.  (Though, if SO *is* the answer, that'd be great since it has the greatest visibility.)

For reference, the question is:

> Why does the TypeScript compiler compile its null-coalescing operators `??` and `?.` to
>
> ```js
> // x ?? y
> x !== null && x !== void 0 ? x : y
>
> // x?.y
> x === null || x === void 0 ? void 0 : x.y;
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```js
> // x ?? y
> x != null ? x : y
>
> // x?.y
> x == null ? void 0 : x.y
> ```
>
> ?

Comment: I’m not actually sure if SO has the greatest visibility. It has the most users, but it also has the most questions.

Comment: Somewhat of a TypeScript SME here - definitely on Stack Overflow, but be sure to ask this question in a way that does not attract close votes as "opinion-based". Usually language design questions end up at least controversial. You are lucky if one of the core contributors show up or you may even get a reply from one of the team members (Anders and Ryan used to be quite active)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Overflow has a [[language-design] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-design) which has a couple of well-received questions about compiler behaviour. Sometimes, questions about language design are closed as opinion-based because we can't look inside the designers' minds, but this question looks like it could have an objectively verifiable answer.

Comment: Always nice to see it worked out well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69843082/4751173

Answer (score 0):

Our [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typescript) site has many questions tagged TypeScript. Be certain to [check the Help Center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and their meta site for additional information.

Comment: Well, I used Software Engineering, and it got two downvotes and was closed as off-topic.

Comment: @dx_over_dt - Deleted too, so I can't comment on whether it was written to meet the guidelines.